# ASP.Net calculate City from ZIP?

Tags: asp.net

i have a user registration.
In this, of course, a user must enter ZIP.

Now I will make a way in which the city is be calculate from the ZIP.

The only idea I have by myself is a database-table (or txt-file) and look in the table / file for the city.

Is this the best / fastest way or is there another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hosting the database yourself is one possibility, another is to use some service on the cloud. Here's one [such service](http://www.geonames.org/export/free-geocoding.html).

Comment: this service is so nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own database, you will have the job of keeping it upto date.

Better to use an internet service. Try this one: http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx